# svnsync synchronize failed on mirror due to try sync a delete operation from main SVN server

Tags: svn

I got errors below when run "svnsync synchronize" on SVN mirror server:

```
svnsync: E160013: '/svn/!svn/txr/144839-36ot/branches/**myfolder**' path not found
svnsync: E175002: Additional errors:
svnsync: E175002: DELETE of '/svn/!svn/txr/144839-36ot/branches/**myfolder**': 404 Not Found
```

The folder "myfolder" is what svnsync tried to delete, but it doesn't existed on mirror SVN because in previously the sync user didn't have permission(now the account have the full permission) to access the folder "myfolder" on main SVN so didn't create/sync it at mirror svn side.

I can use "svn log" to see the creation log from main SVN:

```
r51083 | oxxx | 2011-04-08 22:06:58 +0800 (Fri, 08  4 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /branches/myfolder

Added a branch.
```

But same "svn log" command against mirror get nothing.

Now someone deleted "myfolder" and mirror need to do the same(but mirror doesn't have it). This is causing svnsync always failed and told me 404 Not Found, what can I do to fix it? Thanks in advance!